# Can we tracks time spent on all other apps on the user’s iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have to track the time spent on all other apps on the user's iPhone e.g how much time user spent on SMS , Email, or any other app which is installed from App Store .Is it possible to track this from my iOS app ?

Also can I get the count of apps for particular category ? e.g. In user's iPhone there are 5 app which are in category "Games" , 2 in "Productivity" .

any one know about this please help me.

Answer (score 2):

None of this is possible in a non-jailbroken environment with an App Store app.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to track anything other than what your app does for an App Store app.  Your app is sandboxed and can't access other applications, nor track what they do.